# SQL Query via JDBC connection on JSP page - passing parameter into sql:query

Tags: mysql, jsp, jstl

I have jsp page with select:form. Values in the select form are from the Table 'Publications' from mySql DB. Each option is displayed by the publication's title. I would like to create query which will return me other values than publication's title. How to pass the id parameter to sql:query, which is the result of the onchange JavaScript function?

Below I present the code which I'm using (as for now I didn't find the way to pass id so it is for test case "101"):

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
    <page:jspBody>
         <form:select id="publication" path="publication" onchange="checkId()">
          ...
         </form:select>

        <sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
             url="jdbc:mysql://path" user="root"  password="***"/>

        <sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
             SELECT * from inventory.publication WHERE id="101";
        </sql:query>

        <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
            <input type="text" value="<c:out value="${row.totalPrinting}"/>"/>
        </c:forEach> 
    </page:jspBody>   

  <script>
        function checkId() {
            var selectElement = document.getElementById("publication");
            var x = selectElement.value;
            return x;
        }
  </script>
```

Comment: Javascript is executed in the browser. JSPs are executed in the server. The only way for the server to know about something happening in the browser is to send an HTTP request from the browser to the server. Learn about AJAX. And while you're at it, learn about MVC, and stop using the sql tag library. It's not indended to be used in any serious application. (Read the first sentence of http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL7.html)

Comment: thank @JBNizet for notice: "The JSTL SQL tags for accessing databases are designed for quick prototyping and simple applications"